# React JS get Express JS data sent with render API

Tags: reactjs, express, pug

Is there a way to retrieve the data send with Express JS `render()` API in a React component?
The `express` data is being sent over, but the only level I can catch it is in the `pug` template, but I want to transfer or catch it in a React component so I can retrieve more data from database inside the component.
The main issue is that the data I want to send over is originates from `passport`, after checking if the user is being authenticated.
This is the express route

```
response.render(path.resolve('views', 'account.pug'), {user: request.user});
```

and this is part of the `pug` template

```
body
        #navbar
        #account
```

in which I render this component

```
class Account extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillMount()
    {
        console.log(this.props);
    }

    render()
    {
        return(
            <div class='account'>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I want to know if there is an elegant way to do this, without cookie manipulation or other workarounds.
If not, what would you propose the best way should be to send the data from backend into the React component?

Comment: Just to get this right, you use React in the frontend and express on the server?

Comment: Yes, of course. Express for routing, and React for rendering pages with dynamic data. This is why I need this information from express API in the React component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring your data across the HTTP response, which basically means either header, cookie or body in some way or the other. Technically body is probably easiest. In this case something like a data attribute on the `#account` element which contains all necessary information and is then read at the time you initialise your react components. If you work with a state container like redux you might want to add the user data to the initial state that you might already transfer.

Just to reiterate the result of the comment back and forth. It might not even be necessary to give data to the client side in this specific case because it's data about a logged in user which should be in the server-side session. So creating an endpoint to fetch the data of the "current user" might be enough to fetch it in the frontend without sharing the user id specifically.

Comment: Wouldn't this body attribute be some kind of security issue?

Comment: Depends on the information in it I guess. you didn't exactly say what's in it. But ofc that might be a problem. You cannot easily deal with non public information in the client, because obviously the client (and therefore the user) has access to it.

Comment: Basically I want to transfer an id from my database into the React `Component`. This component would be an account page, so to say. The `get` route that renders this account page is protected using `passport`(can only access if logged it, etc). I want to achieve rendering this component with data from database, but I can only do so based on the user's id(that I am trying to get from backend). Is there an alternate way to do this?

Comment: Right, but that should be fine? I mean the user probably can know their ID and anything you want to show them in the account page?

Comment: The ID should not be visible. Everything else, yeah, I guess so.

Comment: Passport has a persistent user session unless you disabled that. So technically having an endpoint to request the "current user" data should do the trick without giving anything to react. The end point should know from passports session which user is making the request.

Answer (score 0):

You should render the data directly into the Component's constructor.  The [unescaped interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) from pug will handle this without the need for any secondary API call back to the server.

```
class Account extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state.user = !{JSON.stringify(user)};
    }
    ...
```

Our app does something very similar with Vue.js, it is very efficient and very high performance from the user's perspective.

Note: my reactjs knowledge is limited, so `this.state.user` might not be the exact place you need it rendered.  Still, I am confident this the place where you should drop the data into React on the server.

Comment: `stringify`-ing the `user` does not work. Trying to log this gives me the error that the `user` is not defined.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full function used to render the pug template.  That's the second part of your problem.

Comment: Added the `React` component. Still not sure what to use so that I catch the response from `express js`'s middleware.

Comment: Please edit your original question, not my answer.  Your problem is not in the React component, it is in the node.js route.